# Validating users with Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following to validate my user which works but i wish to incoperate roles so I used the reg iis to add the standard tables aspnet_UsersInRoles.

What I basically want is the ability to have variables canView canDelete canEdit and that I can just access them when my dal is called.

```
protected void btnLogin_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Users _loginUser = _dal.VerifyPassword(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);

    if (failedLogin == false)
        lblerror.Text = "Invalid Login";
    else
    {


        UserData userData = new UserData
        {
            FirstName = _loginUser
        };
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
          1,                                     // ticket version
          _loginUser.UserName,                              // authenticated username
          DateTime.Now,                          // issueDate
          DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),           // expiryDate
          isPersistent,                          // true to persist across browser sessions
          userData,                              // can be used to store additional user data
          FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);  // the path for the cookie

        // Encrypt the ticket using the machine key
        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

        // Add the cookie to the request to save it
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        lblerror.Text = "Success!";

        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }

}
```

My Question is how would i adapt the following routine to inlcude the roles aspnet_UsersInRoles table to check if has administrative privellages Of a guid type of ED85788D-72DA-4D0A-8D5E-B5378FC00592.

```
public Users VerifyPassword(string userName, string password)
{
    //The ".FirstOrDefault()" method will return either the first matched
    //result or null
    Users myUser = SoccerEntities.Users
        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName
                     && u.password == password);



    if (myUser == null)    //User was not found
    {
        //Proceed with your login process...
        return myUser;
    }
    else    //User was  found
    {
        if (isPlayerdb(userName))
            isPlayer = true;
        if (isAdmindb(userName))
            isAdmin = true;

        return myUser;        
        //Do something to let them know that their credentials were not valid
    }
}
```

Cause at min im doing this setting the isAdmin variable on a other function isAdmindb so thats three hits to db which is not very effiecent

```
protected bool isAdmindb(string userName)
{

    try{
           Users adminUsers = (from users in SoccerEntities.Users
                       where users.roleId == new Guid("ED85788D-72DA-4D0A-8D5E-B5378FC00592") && users.UserName == userName
                       select users).FirstOrDefault();

        if (adminUsers != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new EntityContextException("isAdmin failed.", ex);
    }
}
```

Edit a had a typo in my return !!!

Comment: `VerifyPassword()` always returns `null`? What's the point of that?

Comment: i had a typo sorry updated with correct code

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. Good job on your first post!

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> public Users VerifyPassword(string userName, string password)
> {
>     //The ".FirstOrDefault()" method will return either the first matched
>     //result or null
>     Users myUser = SoccerEntities.Users
>         .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName
>                      && u.password == password);
>
>
>
>     if (myUser == null)    //User was not found
>     {
>         //Proceed with your login process...
>         return myUser;
>     }
>     else    //User was  found
>     {
>         if (isPlayerdb(userName))
>             isPlayer = true;
>         if (isAdmindb(userName))
>             isAdmin = true;
>
>         return myUser;        
>         //Do something to let them know that their credentials were not valid
>     }
> }
> ```

The comments in this method don't serve any purpose an don't add any value to the code, so get rid of them. Comments should describe **why** something is done but shouldn't state the obvious.

A class named `Users` implies to hold a collections of `User` but in your case it seems to be singular so you should rename this class to `User`.

Not using braces `{}` will lead to error prone code. You should use them always although they might be optional.

The `else` part is redundant because if `myUser == null` it won't be reached, you should get rid of the `else`.

If for instance `isAdmin` had been `true` before this call it will stay that way which is bad. Just assign the returned value of `isAdmindb` to the variable. The same goes for `isPlayer`.

Applying this points except for `Users` vs `User`

```
public Users VerifyPassword(string userName, string password)
{

    Users user = SoccerEntities.Users
        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName
                     && u.password == password);

    if (user == null) { return null; }

    isPlayer = isPlayerdb(userName);

    isAdmin = isAdmindb(userName);

    return user;        

}
```

looks much cleaner, doesn't it ? But hold on, we can do better.

If we take a look at `isAdmindb()` we notice at first, that the method name doesn't match the [NET naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) regarding the used case of the name. Method names should be named using `PascalCase` casing.

The next thing is that a user is considered an admin if its `roleId` matches a specific `Guid`. So let us take this `Guid` and use it in the `VerifyPassword()` method. But wait, this doesn't seem right because the responsibility of that method should be only to verify that the used username and password are correct. So there shouldn't be anything related like in the former method with the `isAdmin` stuff.

So let us change the `isAdmindb()` method to take a `Users` opject as a method argument and compare the user's `roleId` with the said `Guid` which we extract to a class member constant.

```
private const Guid adminRoleId = new Guid("ED85788D-72DA-4D0A-8D5E-B5378FC00592");
protected bool IsAdmin(Users user)
{
    return user.roleId == adminRoleId ;
}
```

now thats short and readable and doesn't need to hit the db.

Now we should take the `VerifyPassword()` and change it to `GetUser()` and remove all this stuff about the `isAdmin` and `isPlayer` leaving only this

```
public Users GetUser(string userName, string password)
{

    return SoccerEntities.Users
        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName
                     && u.password == password);
}
```

Now let us add a `FormsAuthenticationTicket GetAuthenticationTicket(Users)`  method which will do some of the work which had formerly been done by the eventhandler of that button.

```
private FormsAuthenticationTicket GetAuthenticationTicket(Users user)
{
    return new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
          version: 1,                                     
          name: user.UserName,                           
          issueDate: DateTime.Now,                        
          expiration: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),        
          isPersistent: isPersistent,                     
          userData: user.ToString(),                             
          cookiePath: FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
}
```

as you see by using named arguments there is no need for any comment anymore.

Now the former eventhandler code will look like

```
protected void btnLogin_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Users user = GetUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);

    if (user == null)
    {
        lblerror.Text = "Invalid Login";
        return;
    }

    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = GetAuthenticationTicket(user);

    isAdmin = IsAdmin(user);
    isPlayer = IsPlayer(user); // should be implemented by you in a similiar way

    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    lblerror.Text = "Success!";

    Response.Redirect("default.aspx");


}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Naming**

```
Users adminUsers = (from users in SoccerEntities.Users
                       where users.roleId == new Guid("ED85788D-72DA-4D0A-8D5E-B5378FC00592") && users.UserName == userName
                       select users).FirstOrDefault();
```

It's not clear why the type is called `Users` or why the variable is called `adminUsers` when both the type and the variable appear to refer to only a single instance. Consider `User` and `adminUser` instead.

**Var**

Use `var` when the type of the local variable is obvious by its assignment.

```
UserData userData = new UserData
        {
            FirstName = _loginUser
        };
```

Should be

```
 var userData = new UserData
        {
            FirstName = _loginUser
        };
```

**Design**

You have a lot of logic in what looks to be view code behind. Consider a framework such as MVVM to separate your view and domain logic.

I am concerned that your DAL has an `isPlayer` field on it. What does this do? It sounds like it would be better to place this in your `Users` object.

`isAdminDB` seems like a useless function to me. Why go back to the database to get a field that should be on your object?

Instead, what's wrong with this?

```
public Users VerifyPassword(string userName, string password)
{
    //The ".FirstOrDefault()" method will return either the first matched
    //result or null
    Users myUser = SoccerEntities.Users
        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName
                     && u.password == password);



    if (myUser == null)    //User was not found
    {
        //Proceed with your login process...
        return myUser;
    }
    else    //User was  found
    {
        if (isPlayerdb(userName))
            isPlayer = true;

        if(myUser.roleId == "ED85788D-72DA-4D0A-8D5E-B5378FC00592")
        {
            isAdmin = true;
        }

        return myUser;        
        //Do something to let them know that their credentials were not valid
    }
}
```

Presumably you can do the same with your `isPlayerdb` function.

Also, you have a massive magic string with your GUID. Make it a const, give it a name. No maintenance developer is going to know what "ED85788D-72DA-4D0A-8D5E-B5378FC00592" means off the top of their head.

Lastly, your use of GUIDs is concerning to me. I'm not convinced this is the best way to represent the role for a user. Instead, could you give the user a reference to the object from the role table? If you brought this over at the same time you wouldn't even need to check. Just go:

```
if(myUser.Role.Type == Admin)
```

or something like that.

Comment: how do i had constants in c# though is that not just a vb thing

Comment: well then how would you suggest i add the type into the role table then

Comment: You very much can use constants in C#. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: As for how to add the "type" into the role table, I recommend adding a field to your role table called "type" with either "admin" or "player" entered as values.